# Any alternative way to upgrade OpenBSD

Tags: kernel, software-update, openbsd

I have an older network access controller running OpenBSD 3.9. Looking over man pages and website for OpenBSD the process to update still looks locked in the old days - manual updates only one step at a time. Is there not a way to automate or otherwise move from the half decade old (or older) version I have now to streamline this update process? At this rate I would have days of updating dozens of version changes over the years to do - if not more like weeks... I hesitate to just copy the docroot and basic files I know about not stock in the distribution and then use a new fresh clean install - because I don't know what else has been modified on this NAC as part of their package of proprietary solutions.

Ideas welcome

Answer (score 1):

There isn't going to be an automated process, unless the vendor is still supporting the product and provides one. OpenBSD won't assume it knows what changes you made, why, and how to merge it if necessary, so part of the process expects an admin to merge incremental changes between versions.

*So many changes have been made over the years, you may find that even if you follow the process, the custom stuff on the hardware still might not work - feature/api changes, configs, network, sudo is now a package, and even dropped architectures...and I hope you have all the sources!*

Idea: You could attempt to compare a clean 3.9 install vs. what you have now to determine the custom/changed files; And/or try to upgrade to 4.0 and record the changes during `sysmerge`; make copies of everything. Do a fresh install of the latest 6.0, then manually merge those changes and files back...

...*It sounds like a nightmare; but there is always the possibility that the changes aren't actually major, or are easily contained.*

I think you'll get the best, suggestions from OpenBSD's `misc` mailing list (someone might even own your device) but be prepared for...'flak'

Comment: thanks - I will continue reading - so far the only way I can see is to use the manual method incrementally. Most of the device's functionality is built into perl scripts which will work on any platform really - may need to modify what they act on - but overall I think I may just do a clean install on a second drive and migrate the webroot and various configs over. I will need to find drivers for the 4 port nic and random number generator - the board is dremmeled and the partnumber/model numbers on some things are hidden - reminds me of when I was in the Navy as an Electronics Tech

Comment: sounds like there is hope if its mostly perl! I'd suggest reading all the Upgrade Guides for the major changes; please update us if it works out

Comment: OK so anyone have a suggestion for which method to backup the thing or which directories to save to compare? I'm thinking copy everything to a backup or second HDD then format and install newest build OS then copy the user and webroot file. Need ideas on how to do a compare on anything else. I'm guessing I will have to rebuild security rules and make sure the users exist which the Perl is written for. Not sure if Perl is still going to be as secure as it was once thought to be for the admin functions. Basically it is setup to play multiple roles auth firewall walled garden billing